# Vertical center a span with font-awesome 5 SVG icon in Bootstrap Panel Heading

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, panel, font-awesome-5

I have this code:

```
   <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-11 left">
                    <button style="display: inline-block;" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle"> <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></button>
                    <h3 style="display: inline-block;" class="panel-title uppercased green">&nbsp; Twitter</h3>
                </div>                   
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <span class="clickable right"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-chevron-circle-up"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have a problem to center vertically col-md-1 and span with font-awesome chevron icon.
This is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KOEd.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want the col-md-1 on the same line as other elements?

Comment: exactly in the middle

Comment: I don't get it... https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/WMavVQ This is your code, in the middle...uhm...

Comment: Vedo che sei di Milano, quindi scrivo in italiano, in pratica non riesco ad allinearlo verticalmente. Ho messo solo la parte del panel heading, ti passo il resto se vuoi

Comment: Ok, but let's keep the conversation in english..if you have green icon-text-icon, vertical align means everything on one line, right? Feel free to fork the Pen and add more context

Comment: ok i add in your codeopen thank you

Comment: you have to fork it and save it, otherwise I won't see your changes

Comment: I understood you did not put the bootstrap cdn

Comment: I added, but provide the link that best matches your environment! Also for a better understanding you can upload an image with the desired behavior

Comment: yep you can add this: <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: Updated, but as expected, nothing has changed... Can you upload an image with the desired behavior?

Comment: yes i have upload an image, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is beacuse the button inside the left div has a certain height that affects also the element on the right.

Just add a line-height equals to the height of the green button:

```
.clickable i {
  line-height: 34px;
}
```

I also fixed your typo in icon class. There's an extra 'b' that causes the non-rendering of the twitter icon.

```
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
```

I have updated the [codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/WMavVQ).

I add a wrapper and background color, so you can easily see that now it's aligned correctly.

Comment: Ok i understand, but there's another problem, doesn't work if you use font-awesone script: <head>
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>  because the script overwrites tag

Comment: @Andrea I have update the codepen, the code was not working anymore because that JS changes the i into a svg. It was pretty easy to fix!

Comment: @Andrea You're welcome! Don't forget to upvote it! Thanks ;)

Comment: I have just started, when I reach the first 15 reputations I will vote for your post immediately. Happy day

Comment: i solved in this mode:   <span class="clickable right">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-chevron-circle-up" id="actionChevronUp"></i>
                        <i style="display:none" class="fa fa-2x fa-chevron-circle-down" id="actionChevronDown"></i>
                    </span>